# Jquery constant window height

Tags: jquery, css, height, constants

So I've been trying to make a script that checks the constant window height, here is what I have so far:

But when the document is ready, it doesn't pass the height into the Variable.

All I get is height: 0px;

I've tried changing the var to var winHeight = $(window).height();

Which gives me the number I need, but doesn't update if the window is resized.

Have I missed something?

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        var winHeight = 0;          
        $(window).resize(function() {
          winHeight = $(window).height();         
        });
        $(".l_main").css("height", winHeight);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to put a CSS rule that gives `height: 100vh;` It's way better. The browser will automatically give it window height.

Comment: @Omri Luzon - Awesome, I shall try this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you only set the `css()` when the page loads. You also need to do it when the `resize` event happens, so put that call inside the `resize` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".l_main").css("height", $(window).height());      
  }).resize();
});
```

You should note however, that this would be much better achieved using CSS only. For example:

```
.l_main { height: 100%; }
```

You just need to ensure that all parent elements of `.l_main` have a `height` set too.

Comment: Why `.resize();` at the end?

Comment: To trigger the event when the page loads so that the `css()` call happens on load too, as that's what OPs original code does

Comment: Awesome, you area legend!
I realize it is a simple thing to do, but I'm still learning jQuery (which is amazing)
I'm using Display:Flex to get everything centered to the screen, so the 100% wouldn't work well :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default value on load, and also when you resize.
Try something like this :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();  
    $(".l_main").css("height", winHeight);        
    $(window).resize(function() {
      winHeight = $(window).height(); 
      $(".l_main").css("height", winHeight);        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: For anyone that want to know, this works as well!!
Thanks a lot!